# While loop iteration for specified times

Tags: jmeter

I have a while loop, for this while loop I want to iterate only for 20 times and perform the child operations, how can I achieve this in JMeter. 
Any help will be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter).